# How to properly create an ODBC connection MariaDB

Tags: server, mariadb, odbc, port, driver

I'm on a Windows server and I have installed 2 things:

**- MariaDB version 10.5.9**

**- MariaDB ODBC Driver version 3.1.13**

Now I'm using the **ODBC Data Source Administrator** to create an **ODBC connection**. So I clicked on **'Add'**, chose **MariaDB ODBC** driver and got the following screen in front of me:

[image]

I really have no clue what to fill under **Server Name, Port, User Name and Password**. Especially the **Server name** seems quiet hard because I don't know where to get it from....

Comment: where is your server? if local localhost if an external as the provider port is usualy 3306 username is a user that you have enterered else it is root, and you must have entered a password when you8 installed it.

Comment: How can I check where my server is? Also what is my user name?

Comment: you said you installed your server, so you should know where it is, we can't ell you that. by default one user must exist it is root.

Comment: @nbk can you join in so I can tell you exactly what's going on? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235648/discussion-about-server